# Store Symfony2 session in redis

Tags: php, symfony, redis

I want to store the user sessions in Redis to make them usable for Symfony2 and node.js.

Symfony2 supports MySQL and PostgreSQL as session storage but I would like to use Redis.

I found this new pull request which implements already a `RedisSessionHandler`:
https://github.com/Baachi/symfony/blob/redis-session-storage/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/RedisSessionHandler.php

I just didn't found anything about if it is safe to use. Has somebody some infos or is there already some other fix (maybe a bundle) available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or is there already some other fix (maybe a bundle) available?

Linked `RedisSessionHandler` requires [phpredis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis) extension, that can be configured to act as session handler in php.ini (sessions will be stored with keys `$key = 'PHPREDIS_SESSION:'.$hash;`)

Comment: Hi,I haved built the phpredis extension and configured my php.ini. Than I restarted apache and logged in again. I looked through the tmp folder and there are no sess* files anymore but when I want to look at redis there also don't seem to be any entries (redis-cli> KEYS *)

Comment: And does saving and retrieving values from session between pages work?

Comment: I now restarted the computer and followed your approach. Retrieving session attributes work fine and I also can't find any cache file similar to the sessionid in the browser. Can it be that redis hides the sessions in the cli? Setting keys and values manuelly work with redis even after a restart

Comment: No, redis-cli doe not hide any keys. If you are using symfony, don't you have registered any of it's session handlers? Can you check phpinfo to see if redis is set as session handler and run simple script `<?php session_start(); exit; ?>` to see if there are any new keys in redis-cli ?

Comment: phpinfo=> Registered save handlers: files user redis.             I executed youre session testing script and it works. You are right, symfony seems to ignore the php.ini session handler and uses its own. So you are also right with registering their redis session handler. I found the symfony config reference which has these session options (http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/framework.html) under session_handler_id I can define my own session service (at least I assume this). How to do this is explained somewhere else in the doc

Comment: You probably already have defined session service in symfony, clean symfony installation uses sessions handler from php.ini

Comment: yep but for some reason they remove the redis implementation from the repository (there where already three requests in the past which got removed) and because redis is not available anymore (there is a new pr on that...) it fallbacks to some other method :)